# JSON date format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Tags: json, spring

In my Spring controller I want to get JSON array. I have startDateTime and endDateTime. I want it in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" format. ex: 2014-03-14 05:00. But when I create JSON array it only shows as "yyyy-MM-dd" ex:2014-03-14.

Here is my **Controller**;

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    for (Message message1 : message) {
                    JSONObject messageJSON = new JSONObject();
                    StringBuilder startDateTime = new StringBuilder(dateformat.format(message1.getMessageStartDateTime()));
                    StringBuilder endDateTime = new StringBuilder(dateformat.format(message1.getMessageEndDateTime()));
                    System.out.println("statdateTime: "+startDateTime);
                    messageJSON.put("messageId", message1.getMessageId());
                    messageJSON.put("messageDescription", message1.getMessageDescription());
                    messageJSON.put("messageStartDateTime", message1.getMessageStartDateTime());
                    messageJSON.put("messageEndDateTime", message1.getMessageEndDateTime());
                    messageArray.add(messageJSON);
                }
```

Help out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about instead of

```
messageJSON.put("messageStartDateTime", message1.getMessageStartDateTime());
messageJSON.put("messageEndDateTime", message1.getMessageEndDateTime());
```

you do

```
messageJSON.put("messageStartDateTime", startDateTime.toString());
messageJSON.put("messageEndDateTime", endDateTime.toString());
```

?